# internal server error when trying to access asp.net core app hosted in IIS 10

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I used VS2017 to create an ASP.NET core API app, just a simple one.. I didn't even make any changes to it. it was able to compile just fine, able to debug in IIS Express just fine.. you know, the default /api/values which returns {value1, value2}..  just the default..

I tried to host it in IIS 10 on Windows 10. Added an application pool which has .NET CLR version set to "No managed code", keeping everything else as default. Using VS2017, published to folder, set IIS to point to that folder, set it to use port 8080. tried accessing it in browser with 127.0.0.1:8080/api/values and.. HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error. why? what did I not do?

In command prompt, typing dotnet --info shows the version as 2.1.200, and the .net framework as 2.0.7. In fact, I was even able to run the app directly from the command prompt by typing "dotnet .dll" and it would show listening on port 5000 and I was able to use browser to access 127.0.0.1:5000/api/values and the {values1, values2} would appear in the browser. But why is it that I can't use IIS to host it?

Talking about using command prompt to run the app using kestrel, I noticed a strange thing. setting the args in configure, I was able to use urls to dynamically change the port that kestrel is listening on, and I was able to enable remote access to kestrel using dotnet .dll --urls http://*:5050 for example, and it works fine.. BUT.. when I set the port to 6000 or greater, kestrel would say it's listening on that port, but remote client would not be able to access it. has anyone encountered this? using ports in the range of 5000~5999 works fine..  why?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the following:

1. .NET Core Hosting Bundle installed on the hosting server - https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all
2. Application Pool .NET CLR version set to "No Managed Code"
3. Ensure that the Application Pool Identity user has read permissions on the published folder.

For details check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: so sorry for the trouble.. I realized I didn't install the hosting bundle.. that's the most important part for hosting in IIS.. and yet I missed that.. so sorry for the trouble.. and thanks so much for enlightening me. :)

Comment: granted.. I can now use funny ports like 7788, instead of being limited to 5000~5999 when using kestrel directly.. still don't quite understand why there's such a restriction.. don't see it mentioned anywhere..  but anyway, thanks for helping me. :)